# Android: Kill all processes in an application

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

In my application I have an "Application" and several Activities. I would like to kill my application after a specific time (ex. 3 minutes) after user pressed the Home button. I'm able to finish the "Application"s process but as long as my activities are alive, they tries to start from their last state.

```
Thread isOnDisplayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {



            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer mTimer = new Timer();

                mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, (isApplicationOnDisplay) ? "Application on display" : "APPLICATION ON BACKGROUND");

                        if (!isApplicationOnDisplay) {
                            notOnDisplayTime++;
                            if (notOnDisplayTime >= 10) {

                                Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                            }
                        } else {
                            notOnDisplayTime = 0;
                        }

                    }
                }, 0, 1000);

            }
        });

        isOnDisplayThread.run();
```

P.S. `isApplicationOnDisplay` is a static boolean controlled by every Activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods.

Is there any way to kill all related activities of an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I can't understand why everybody tries to kill his own application...)

Killing an application should *never* be done by an application (though sometimes an task manager has his advantages).

> I'm able to finish the "Application"s process but as long as my activities are alive, they tries to start from their last state.

You have full control about the state handling, you decide if an activity continue with the latest state or not. If you don't want the current behavior, [change it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState), but don't try to kill your application.

To make it short: **The Android OS decides if an application should be killed/stopped or not**

Thats how android is designed and how it should be used...

Comment: I know that it's not a good excersize to kill my own application. But here's the issue, when i exit the application by hitting the home button, after some time while i'm in some other applications, i see a "Force Close" window showing my application's package name. The exception I get is OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Than you should check the stack trace what causes the OOME and fix that. Thats much better than killing your application...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you, finish all activity, close all threads, dont interfere background...:))

Answer (score 0):

All the activities at once kill is not possible.

you should do two things to kill the activities and services

1) @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onDestroy();
        super.onBackPressed();
                }

2) you should apply at change Intent
onDestroy();

3)and if neccessary you should apply
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)